# C++ 2D pixel perfect collision detection libraries?

Tags: c++, qt, sdl, collision-detection, pixel

what are the libraries available to do this which integrate with SDL and QT4 . Are there any existing packages in SDL or QT  which allow for easy implementation of this?. I am looking for for an easy to use library that would allow me to have a functionality like this

> http://www.coreyoneil.com/portfolio/index.php?project=5

a link to the Api/class example/tutorial which implements pixel-perfect collision detection in your stated library is what i am looking for.

> Edit: Please check the above link to
>   understand what i mean by pixel
>   perfect.

Comment: in box2d forums i had found this topic regarding pixel perfect collision detection http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=5133&p=24224&hilit=pixel+perfect+collision#p24224 which indicates that the kind of implementation i am looking for and have linked to is not feasible /possible with box 2d

Comment: Why does it needs to be pixel perfect? Just represent the shape mathematically and use any existing library, like Box2D.

Comment: @unwind yeah it is. i bet you can understand why anyone would want this kind of functionality. The library/classes are easy to use in actionscript3.you pass the objects to the collision array which handles the whole thing.Only after seeing the above link i really came to appreciate the pixel perfectness. I am sure there are already existing libraries in c++ which do this.

Comment: Here is a backup for the link: http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20090618194120/http://www.coreyoneil.com/Flash/CDK/documentation/

Comment: Or better this one: http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20090317074047/http://www.coreyoneil.com/Flash/CDK/index.html and the code on Google: http://code.google.com/p/collisiondetectionkit/

Answer (score 1):

Qt does provide collision test in its [QGraphicsItem](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#collidesWithItem) class. It supoorts path-based shapes. I am not sure if it works with your pixel requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [GameDev](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/584518-reni2d-library---added-shader-supportpixel-perfect-collision/) related post(Reni2D is C with OpenGL so it should fit OK with SDL).

In [HAAF's](http://hge.relishgames.com/overview.html) engine they advertise it as coming soon, so maybe it's worth checking it out also.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you this [Allegro Perfect Collision](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Pixel_Perfect_Collision)

[Allegro.cc](http://www.allegro.cc/) has a great helpful comunity.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[PoxelColl](https://github.com/Poxelcoll/Poxelcoll) provides pixel-perfect collision detection, and supports basic transformations like rotation and scaling. A C++11 port is supported, so it should be compatible with SDL and QT.